# Multiple where clause using C# and SqlKata query engine

Tags: c#, rest, api-gateway, sqlkata

I am working on a small Web API which will use SqlKata in the back end as the query engine to talk to SQL Server. In the documentation, SqlKata says the following in relation to multiple where clauses:

**Multiple fields**
*If you want to filter your query against multiple fields, pass an object that represents col/values.*

```
var query = new Query("Posts").Where(new {
    Year = 2017 ,
    CategoryId = 198 ,
    IsPublished = true,
});
```

My intention is to use query strings to create the WHERE clauses in the back end, but I'm a bit stuck as to how to convert the Key/Value pairs of the query strings into properties of an object to use in the SqlKata query. The request will be highly dynamic in nature, so I can't really use a static object. I am wondering if anyone has any tips on how to construct an object to satisfy these requirements, being that the properties - both the property name and/or value - can be dynamic, as could the number of properties within the object. In my head I could imagine somehow converting the key / value pairs of the query strings into an object at run-time, but I'm stuck on how to achieve that.

I did try the following, but it seems each iteration through the loop the last key/value pair is replaced, so you end up with only the most recent WHERE clause being considered:

```
                    if (request.QueryStringParameters != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var element in request.QueryStringParameters)
                        {
                            CreateCloudWatchLog($"query string {element.Key} value {element.Value}", context, LogLevel.Trace, environmentLogLevel);

                            if (element.Key != "limit")
                            {
                                query = query.Where(element.Key, element.Value);
                            }
                            if (element.Key == "limit")
                            {
                                query = query.Limit(Convert.ToInt32(element.Value));
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I have also tried this approach (query strings => json => dynamic object) but I get the error 'parameter count mismatch' (I am testing with one parameter passed in called 'storenumber' with a value of 399)

```
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request.QueryStringParameters, Formatting.Indented);
                        CreateCloudWatchLog($"Serialised query strings = {json}", context, LogLevel.Trace, environmentLogLevel);
                        var myobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
                        query = query.Where(myobject);
```

Debug logs:

```
[Trace] Serialised query strings =
{
    "storenumber": "399"
}

[Trace] Finished converting JSON to object
[Error] Parameter count mismatch.
```

Comment: Have you tried `.Where(key1, value1).Where(key2, value2)...`?

Comment: mjwills - that was actually my next thought after I posted this. I am going to try serialising the query string dictionary to json, then back into a dynamic object and see if that works. DavidG - I hadn't thought of that, but how would I achieve that if the number of key/value pairs is variable and not known at runtime? Your suggestion would be awesome if I knew there would only be - say - 3 key/value pairs at all times. But in this implementation, there could be one pair, or five pairs, there's no way to tell.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it looks like you can use the [basic where](https://sqlkata.com/docs/where#basic-where) method which takes a property and a value. For example, assuming you have a dictionary of key value pairs, you could do this:

```
var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Year", 2017 },
    { "CategoryId", 198 },
    { "IsPublished", true },
}

var query = new Query("Posts");

foreach(var filter in filters)
{
    query = query.Where(filter.Key, filter.Value);
}
```

Comment: DavidG I did try the loop and using that syntax, but it only seems to add the last key/value pair, so if it loops through 3 sets of key/value pairs it seems to replace the last one on the next iteration.

Comment: Did you do it exactly as I wrote it? Remember that you need to keep storing the `query` on each iteration.

Comment: DavidG I've edited my post to show my version but it's pretty much the same as what you've outlined. In testing, it seems to only consider the most recent key / value pair passed in.

Comment: Well that code is identical to chaining the calls, it should work.

Comment: Maybe I've stuffed up somewhere in my testing. I'll re-check a few things and report back. Thanks DavidG

Comment: This answer has worked. I've figured out the issue. If you wanted to simulate a WHERE IN type clause you can't simply pass in the same key value pair more than once (e.g. store=123&store=233) as only the last one will be passed in. The answer I've accepted works fine as long as each key value pair is unique. Which thinking about it now, makes perfect sense. I will need to consult the documentation to build something around WHERE IN clauses and perhaps passing in the query string as store=123,233 or similar.

Comment: That's because sequential `Where` calls are `AND`ing them together, which would mean `where store = 123 AND store = 233` which obviously makes no sense and is why only the last one is used. If you want to use a `WHERE IN` then you should use `WhereIn("store, new [] {123, 233})`. See [the docs](https://sqlkata.com/docs/where#where-in)